# Rails - Object values not being accessible on a attribute writer method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Study model which have many fields, but I'm having troubles with 1

**profesion_name**

so in my study model I have this

```
class Study < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :profesion_related, :profesion_name
  attr_accessor :profesion_related

  def profesion_related=(id)
    if id.present?
      if self.study_type_id == 4
        if self.country_id == 170
           #some code here
        else
           profesion_parent = Profesion.find(id)
           new_profesion = Profesion.create({g_code: profesion_parent.g_code, mg_code: profesion_parent.mg_code, name: self.profesion_name})
           self.profesion = new_profesion
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but I'm getting an error on the line that create a Profesion, because self.profesion_name is nil

if in my controller I do this

```
  def create
    @study = Study.new(params[:study])
    respond_to do |format| 
      #here  
      puts @study.to_yaml 
      if @study.save
       .....
  end
```

I will see in the console that profesion_name has a value
but if I do this

```
class Study < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def profesion_related=(id)
    puts self.to_yaml
    ....
  end
end
```

I can see that self.profesion_name is empty

Why could this be happening?

Comment: try adding :attr_accessor for :profesion_name as it creates a getter/setter

Comment: @dmoss18 :profesion_name is a db column, is it necessary?, I'm using attr_accessor just for virtual attributes

Comment: Actually, I think if anything you should remove the `attr_accessible` for `:profession_related`. Also, since you are specifically creating a setter, I think it would be clearer to only make it `attr_reader`.

Comment: Can you show what error you're getting? I see no reason why saving `:name` as `nil` should give an error.